# multiple devise authentication realms in a rails application: which is the setting that allows for that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I've a simple rails application; it has a devise authentication mechanism. Then i've added activeadmin, that brings its devise based authentication mechanism.

There are other question and answers about merging the two models. This question is about which is the setting that makes the two authentication realms distinct.

Example. I perform login in the admin page:

```
localhost:3000/admin
```

Here the user model is AdminUser.

then i try to move to a regular (non active-admin) page:

```
localhost:3000/documents
```

Here the user model is User.

here, if I test the `current_user` variable, it is `nil` and not an instance of `AdminUser`. That is: the two authentication areas (i used the word realm but I don't know if it is correct) are kept distinct.

I've searched in the activeamdin initializer, but i couldn't find a setting that contains the information of creating a distinct 'authentication realm'.

#### Update 1 (and possible answer):

They are not distinct.

If i test the current_admin_user, it contains and AdminUser instance.

Answer (score 1):

you have two models User and AdminUser associated with two separate DB tables, right?

do you have separate AA and User model routes inside routes.rb?

finally, you have to set devise settings for `User < AR::Base` model (AA user model already shipped with `activeadmin` gem)

in this case, authentications through User and AdminUser models will be separated according to routes you set giving you 'realms' you asked for..

or i didn't get the question...

`current_admin_user` helper gives you `AdminUser` instance

`current_mega_super_user` helper would give you `MegaSuperUser` instance (by default)